# How to find label text within clicked row of a Gridview using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to find the text of a label within row of an asp.net grid view when anywhere on the row is clicked. I have the gridview shown below with the jquery I'm using underneath. I'm getting a javascript alert box when I click on the row, just no text. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grvAgents" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grvAgents_OnRowDataBound"
                    CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even"
                    ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
                    <Columns>                       
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site" Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSite" CssClass="siteLbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Site") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function BindEvents() {
                $(document).ready(function (e) {
                    $('#grvAgents tr').click(function () {
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var lbl = tr.find('.siteLbl').text();
                        alert(lbl);
                        //                  

                });
                });
            }       

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why your code should not work. However you can try the alternative by referencing the label with the `id` instead of the `class` name.

```
$(function ()
{
     $('#grvAgents tr').click(function () {
        var lbl = $(this).closest('tr').find('span[id*="lblSite"]').text();
        alert(lbl);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(function ()
{
 $('#grvAgents tr').click(function () {
    alert($(this).find('.siteLbl').text());
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the TemplateField Visible="false",so it cannot be find in the output html.
You can hide the control by css：

**STYLE**

```
<style type="text/css">
.hid
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

**TemplateField**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hid" ItemStyle-CssClass="hid">
```

Try it again.